# How to put image on webpage using FTL(Free Markup Template Language)?

Tags: image, templates, html, freemarker

I am interested to know how can we put image using **FTL** (**Free Markup Template Language**) ?
Also how to change font color & style in **FTL**?

Can any1 knows any good learning tutorial of `FTL`?
plz share the link...

Comment: I would suggest adding an external stylesheet to modify the aspect of your template. As for the way of inserting an image in ftl, please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

FTL just generates text on the server, like HTML, CSS, whatever, then the client (browser) just gets the output. So, assuming you generate HTML with FTL, you put images into it with `<img src="...">`. To learn about FreeMarker, go to http://freemarker.org/docs/index.html, of course.

Answer (score 1):

it is same like you are putting an image in a HTML page.

```
<image src="images/someFile.png" class="someClass "/>
```

FTL is a template language. 
So all basic syntax and functionality are the same like html,jsp or any other web page.

Answer (score 1):

Freemarker allows you to assign the src of your image as you would normally do:

```
<img src="yourPath/yourImage.png" alt="..." />
```

Or something like:

```
<#--Where "imgUrl" is where the URL for your image is stored, and "alt" is where the alt text of the image is stored.-->
<img src=${imgUrl} alt=${alt} />
```

The second option is especially useful when working with lists.